# Framework7 ajax not working with Phonegap.?

Tags: ajax, html-framework-7

app.js

```
var $$ =Dom7;

$$.post('about.php', function (data) {
  $$('.login').html(data);
  console.log('Load was performed');
});
```

about.php

```
<?php echo "engin"; ?>
```

index.html

```
<div class="login">Deneme Deneme</div>
```

İt's does not work. Please help.

Comment: Could you please show more details?

Answer (score 1):

Must Have specified the framework 7 version Your are using

> But if you are using v3 you can do it like this

```
app.request.post('about.php', function (data) {
   $$('.login').html(data);
   console.log('Load was performed');
});
```